# How to animate the fontSize of a Text in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

Is there any way to animate the increase/decrease of the `fontSize` in a `Text` widget?

Comment: check `AnimatedDefaultTextStyle`

Comment: @pskink TBH, I just came here to write the answer for the same, but saw your comment.

Comment: yep, the more simple code, the better

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Probably an easier solution would be to use `AnimatedTextStyle`.

```dart
double _size = 10;
  
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      child: Icon(Icons.add),
      onPressed: () => setState(() => _size += 50),
    ),
    body: AnimatedDefaultTextStyle(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: _size),
      child: Text('A'),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: why is it named as Default? Does it mean that we can create custom animation controller?

Comment: @MichałJabłoński It is named "Default" because all the descendant `Text` widget gets the same `TextStyle`. You cannot and need not use `AnimationController` with `AnimatedDefaultTextStyle`.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done in many different ways, like using `AnimationController`, setting up the listener and then calling `setState` on it. But I think a better way would be to use `TweenAnimationBuilder` for your use case. Here's the minimal code:

```dart
double _size = 10;
  
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      child: Icon(Icons.add),
      onPressed: () => setState(() => _size += 30),
    ),
    body: TweenAnimationBuilder<double>(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      tween: Tween<double>(begin: _size, end: _size),
      builder: (_, size, __) => Text('A', style: TextStyle(fontSize: size)),
    ),
  );
}
```