# How to animate Text Field in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I want to make this animation in flutter, it is for a calculator app. How do I change the text field present here?

[This is the animation which I am talking about](https://youtu.be/P-SEBR455Ew)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the content in the textfield, Yet you can animate the label text of your textField using the below package.
It offers Slide, Fade and Typer animation.

[animated_hint_textfield](https://pub.dev/packages/animated_hint_textfield)

Ex:

```
AnimatedTextField(
animationType: Animationtype.slide, //for Slide animations
decoration: InputDecoration(
  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
  border: OutlineInputBorder(
    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 2),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
    ),
  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 2),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
    ),
  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
  ),
hintTexts: [
  'Search for "Bengaluru"',
  'Search for "Mumbai"',
  'Search for "Chennai"',
  ],
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this answer [How to animate the fontSize of a Text in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64797688/how-to-animate-the-fontsize-of-a-text-in-flutter) .

it will help you to animate size of the text. If you need further animation of offset on y axis and fade out you can use many approaches like animated builder, animated opacity but i bet it will be simpler to use simple_animations package.